# TeXStudio External PDF Viewer Error

Tags: texstudio

I'm getting the error "Command txs:///view-pdf-external not defined" when I click on the external viewer. Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have  to define your external viewer in the menu  `Opttrions-> Configure TeX Studio -> Compilations`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the underlying OS is Windows:

1. Download and install SumatraPDF from https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer.html (last accessed 2019-08-12-2255UTC+2)
2. Open TeXstudio and go to `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands -> External PDF viewer` and add the following: `"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" %.pdf` (default path to SumatraPDF, if default install path hasn't been changed during installation process.)
3. Restart TeXstudio, compile `.tex` file, open PDF in external viewer.

Comment: It worked for me